# Email client for visually impaired on Windows 10

Tags: email, windows-10, email-client, accessibility

Several web-browsers are getting better at allowing visually impaired to change settings (i.e. increasing font and resizing frames based on responsive design), but for e-mail clients there seems to be less focus. The solution is often to use windows magnifiers, which quickly makes it confusing for the user to navigate. Increasing standard zoom in Windows messes up navigation, as the e-mail reader windows cannot cope with the zooming.

I have tried out the Windows e-mail-reader and the Apple e-mail-reader as well as Gmails without success. Do you know of any e-mail reader working on Windows 10 that allows for dramatically larger font (i.e. 36ish) without messing up the navigation?

Answer (score 2):

[Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) is no perfect choice either, but it offers some accessibility features out of the box. I can't test it on Windows, but it should all lead to similar results.

- Increasing the font size: Edit/Preferences/Display/Formatting. (Under Linux, you may need to change the font settings under your display manager's settings)
- Increasing "PixelsPerPixels" in the advanced settings, increases everything but fonts: Edit/Preferences/Advanced/General/Config editor, search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`, double-click to change the value, to e.g. 2.5. The changes takes effect immediately.
- For more contrast, choose a different theme: Tools/Add-ons/Themes. You'll have to go through the available themes (use the search box) to find a suitable one.

Sources:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-accessibility-features
- https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/theme-font-size-changer-fixed/reviews/1161898/
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Bad_Eyesight_-_Thunderbird